# Codeception acceptance test not working with firefox

Tags: codeception

I am trying to run an acceptance test on firefox using selenium 3.0.1. I am also using [wp-browser](https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser) `WPWebDriver` module. My acceptance-suit.yml looks like this.

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - \Helper\Acceptance
    - WPWebDriver

config:
      WPWebDriver: 
          url: 'url'
          adminUsername: 'juhi.saxena@gmail.com'
          adminPassword: '123456'
          adminPath: '/wp-admin'
          browser: firefox
          webdriver.gecko.driver: 'bin/geckodriver.exe'
```

On runnuning this `wpcept run acceptance testsCest.php` I get `[Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownServerException]                                                                                                                                                    The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded fro

  m https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases`

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem with Codeception and Firefox by adding `path=''` to the WebDriver config section.

Comment: This fixed my issue with setting up firefox headless testing. By default the path was expected to be `/wd/hub` but geckodriver starts without it, and without a way to change it (it listens on 127.0.0.1:4444)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '.exe'.

I'm running successfully with `webdriver.gecko.driver: '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'`.

Also, have you placed the geckodriver.exe in the path?